# WiFi connected but internet not working on Kali Linux (dual boot)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

During the installation of Kali I skipped the network section which I couldn’t fill out at the time. Now in Kali I can connect to the WiFi but can not do anything on the internet like web browsing. I have already tried updating my distros and using service network-manager restart but that raises another error. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: attach a screenshot, please

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5362/108618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error with DNS server. To fix:
Open the terminal. Then write:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf >/dev/null
```

Then reboot the computer.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i can help you but **i can't promise anything**.

**(** *copy with ctrl+'c' paste with ctrl+shift+'v' cause ctrl+something in the terminal is a command to interact with programs running in the terminal* **)**

go **open your terminal** and type: `ping google.com`

if the output says something like: `"ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution"` follow this steps:

- first we are going to open the resolv.conf file with `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
- then type `"nameserver 8.8.8.8"`
- press enter to use the next line
- type `"nameserver 8.8.4.4"`
- press ctrl + 'x'
- press 'y'
- press enter (return)
- type `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

then we will restart the network manager cause it may solve some problems :)

- type (still in terminal) `sudo service NetworkManager restart`
- it may cause an error that says something like `did not find service NetworkManager` if so: instead of `NetworkManager` use `network-manager`. If this also throws an error then idk maybe i f**** up lmao.

finally we type `ping google.com` again, should be working now. If it doesn't, i am sry i can't help.

[**MYSOURCE**](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution#:%7E:text=The%20%22Temporary%20failure%20in%20name%20resolution%22%20error%20occurs%20when%20the,show%20up%20on%20your%20system.)

**some other stuff:**

RUN THIS ON YOUR TERMINAL

- systemctl enable systemd-networkd
- systemctl enable systemd-resolved
- systemctl start systemd-networkd
- systemctl start systemd-resolved
- ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
- service resolvconf restart
- service network-manager restart
- ping google.com

**DISCLAIMER:**

the other stuff did not work for me but maybe for u idk

Answer (score 1):

I once had this issue with a previous version of Kali Linux. What I did to fix it was I just reinstalled it.

It might seem like not a good idea but backup your files and reinstall.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, is I downloaded systemd-resolved from official debian repo. Installed and set up DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, then wifi started working for me.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).